Use NodeJS CLI flags when running vitest node --enable-experimental-regexp-engine
I have a NodeJS backend, where I would like to use the new alternative RegExp engine in v8. This is enable when I start node like this node --enable-experimental-regexp-engine some-script.js.
When running vitest, how can I pass this flag? In my package.json my test script is simply this:
  "scripts": {
    "test": "vitest --reporter=verbose",
  },


Vitest supports passing arguments to node through the configuration block test.poolOptions.forks.argv. See https://vitest.dev/config/#pooloptions-forks-execargv
There are also additional options for other pool types, such as "threads", "vmThreads", and "vmForks". Use the appropriate option based on the pool type you are using. At the time of writing this, the default is "forks".
Example:
import { defineConfig } from "vitest/config";

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    pool: "forks",
    poolOptions: {
      forks: {
        execArgv: [
          "--enable-experimental-regexp-engine",
        ]
      }
    }
  },
});


